# Flutter: Can I update Table fields using Sql_conn package?

Tags: sql, flutter

Im using Sql_conn package to connect and display data from DB-> https://pub.dev/packages/sql_conn/score

And I wanted to know if I can somehow UPDATE Table Fields with this package (I haven't found any info, there is only Read and Write function)

And if there is no way I can UPDATE tables, how can I do it, is there other solutions?

(P.S: I heard about SQLlite, but don't know what it reperesents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
///to connect in database:
await SqlConn.connect(
        ip: '192.168.0.1',
        port: '3306',
        databaseName: 'MyDatabase',
        username: 'root',
        password: 'root');
    

/// to update a column named col1 with value new value where table id = 1 in table named myTable: 
var res = await SqlConn.write("UPDATE myTable SET col1 = 'new value' WHERE id = '1' ");
print(res.toString());
```

You can read the doc:
https://pub.dev/packages/sql_conn/example

Comment: Even tho there is no example except SELECT, it worked perfectly, thanks